# What is complexity of this recursive algorithm which has two for loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How can i found complexity of this algorithm? I think i can use Master Theorem but there are 2 for loop.

```
int fonksiyon(int n) 
{

    if (n<2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            a = a + fonksiyon(n / 2);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
            {
                a = a + 1;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your second loop is O(n^2)... The first is O(n), but multiplied by the runtime of your outer function (n*log(n), for example). For simplification, I'd say the overall function runtime is just O(n^2) since the second loop will run more than the loop+recursion

Answer (score -1):

```
int fonksiyon(int n) 
{
    if (n<2)
    {
        return 1;                               -- O(1)
    }
    else
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            a = a + fonksiyon(n / 2);           --O(n)
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
            {
                a = a + 1;                       --O(n^2)
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

So the overall complexity would be O(1)log n + O(n)log n + O(n^2)log n ≈ **O(n^2 log n)**

Comment: You need to include the fact that the recursive calls also all execute the second loop of O(n²). The labeling with O(nlogn) seems to ignore that part.

Comment: Yes, I missed it. Thanks for marking it out. Every statement will have impact of recursion and will execute in multiple of (log n).